# sigabrt error when loading nib files

Tags: iphone

I am working on a project in which I start with I have a nav controller. I load a login page first then move to a login success page where I have few buttons to click, when I click on any of the button here I get this error.  When I tried to debug the code, I hav a break point at the button click method, before it executes any code there I get this. Here is the log. Can any one please help me with this. Thanks in advance

```
2010-10-07 23:15:28.868 Cattle_try1[14417:207] -[__NSCFType onYardMapBtnClick]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6149a40
2010-10-07 23:15:28.872 Cattle_try1[14417:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType onYardMapBtnClick]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6149a40'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02655b99 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x027a540e objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x026576ab -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x025c72b6 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x025c6e72 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   UIKit                               0x002b47f8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    6   UIKit                               0x0033fde0 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x00342262 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    8   UIKit                               0x00340e0f -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    9   UIKit                               0x002d83d0 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
    10  UIKit                               0x002b9cb4 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    11  UIKit                               0x002be9bf _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7672
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x02f35822 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x02636ff4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x02597807 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x02594a93 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x02594350 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x02594271 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x02f3400c GSEventRunModal + 217
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x02f340d1 GSEventRun + 115
    20  UIKit                               0x002c2af2 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    21  Cattle_try1                         0x00002338 main + 102
    22  Cattle_try1                         0x000022c9 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
kill
quit
```

The Debugger has exited with status 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the solution, but at the least do a backtrace to see if you can see exactly where it's dying.

Build and Debug the app and run the app until you get the error. Then in the console (where your SIGABRT error appears) type

```
bt
```

and the Return key. If you're fortunate it will tell you where it failed. You're looking for the highest (earliest written to the console) file and line number, probably one of your view controllers, a .m file.

Answer (score 2):

It is very likely that you are not retaining the object you are trying to access. But if you don't include the code it's hard to tell.

Comment: Make sure you're following Apple's guidelines for memory management of nib objects. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmNibObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004998-SW2